# Simple Spatial Lines Grid vs. Point Data Regression

Tags: r, regression, geospatial, qgis

I have point data for wildlife occurrences and would like to run a simple regression in QGIS or R that correlates where data has been collected relative to a grid layer (vector / spatialLines) I've created. The forest layer was created by first creating a grid at 1 km x 1 km resolution which covered my entire country of interest. I then clipped this grid to areas where forest cover is above a specified threshold. Any suggestions on how to go about this? Thank you!

Comment: Your post does not contain enough information for specific help. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I would suggest to start with `terra:rasterize()` function.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.